# Video was encoded with a new width + height along with the old one. Can I re-encode with just the old dimensions using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I've got a video out of OBS that play's normally on my system if I open it with VLC for example, but when I import it into my editor (Adobe Premiere) it gets weirdly cropped down. When inspecting the data for the video it's because for some reason the video gets encoded with a new width and height over top of the old one! Is there a way using ffmpeg to re-encode/transcode the video to a new file with only the original width and height?

[image]

Bonus question: would there be a way for me to extract the audio channels from my video as separate .mp3s? There are 4 audio channels on the video

Answer (score 0):

Every time you reencode a video you will lose quality. Scaling the video up will not reintroduce details that were lost when it was scaled down.